# Comparing date field object with global variable "now" gives unexpected result

Tags: datetime, globals

The goal is to show a word when date field qualifies for *tomorrow* or *today* instead of numeric date.

Setting and calling variables:

```
{% set deliveryDate = order.deliveryDate %}
{% set tomorrow = now|date_modify("+ 1 day") %}

{% if deliveryDate == tomorrow %}
  {% set deliveryDate = "tomorrow" %}
{% elseif deliveryDate == now %}
  {% set deliveryDate = "today" %}
{% else %}
  {% set deliveryDate = deliveryDate|date("d.m.Y") %}
{% endif %}
```

My *date field* has selected value of tomorrow whereas the first statement should be truthy.

So I think I'm comparing two objects with the same values but different classes?
I had figured it out by formatting the date objects to strings using [day()](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/templating/datetime.html#day) filter.

But why is THAT happening on the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`now` represents the current `DateTime` so unless you specify exactly the correct time in your field the condition `deliveryDate == now` will never become true. If the user visits the page one second earlier or one second later the condition will fail.

For example: if your date is `2018-06-13 12:00:00` and `now` is `2018-06-13 12:00:01` both of your conditions will always fail. `now|date_modify("+ 1 day")` will result in `2018-06-14 12:00:01` and `12:00:00` is not `12:00:01`

you'll need to equalize the time or format it differently

```
{% if deliveryDate.modify('midnight') == tomorrow.modify('midnight') %}
```

or

```
{% if deliveryDate.format('Y.m.d') == tomorrow.format('Y.m.d') %}
```

You can read more about it in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: Understand @robin I just had no idea that a time parameter is included within `now` variable.